# django-storges support for CloudFront signed URL

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-cloudfront, python-django-storages

I want to use [CloudFront's signed URLs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-signed-urls.html) rather than plain unsigned URLs.

[django-storages](https://django-storages.readthedocs.io/en/latest/backends/amazon-S3.html) gives the option of [`AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN`](https://django-storages.readthedocs.io/en/latest/backends/amazon-S3.html#cloudfront) but then it generates unsigned URLs from CloudFront's subdomain. By default `AWS_QUERYSTRING_AUTH` is `True` and it does generate signed URLs for S3. Any way to generate signed URLs for CloudFront.

This is the setting I am looking to turn on, but due to unsigned URLs I disabled it.
[Settings I am looking to turn on for My distribution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fZ1XR.png)

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: Not till now. You can try bounty.

Comment: I figured it out, could you please check my answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, so the signed URLs are supported now in django-storages development version since [this commit](https://github.com/jschneier/django-storages/commit/b116e3a235323144cda6d3cc5a5cb27baf076ee2) (see [thread for more info](https://github.com/jschneier/django-storages/pull/587))

The version is not yet published on pip, so you can add it to your requirements like this:

```
-e git+git://github.com/jschneier/django-storages.git@b116e3a235323144cda6d3cc5a5cb27baf076ee2#egg=django-storages-dev
```

Then you have to update your options:

```
AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN = "Your cloudfront domain" # something like xxxxx.cloudfront.net
AWS_CLOUDFRONT_KEY_ID = "YOUR_CLOUDFRONT_KEY_ID"
with open(os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "cert.pem")) as aws_cert:
    AWS_CLOUDFRONT_KEY = aws_cert.read().encode('ascii')
```

And that's it. The default expiration timeout is 24 hours, not sure how to change it.

Note that CloudFront key is not the same one as you use for other AWS services. You have to generate it using your root AWS account (not an IAM user). See [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-trusted-signers.html#private-content-creating-cloudfront-key-pairs)

Comment: I've been struggling with this. I eventually figured that the I should be the ID of the public key you upload to AWS whereas the key you read locally should be the private key. The issue though I have is that all URLs that are generated return HTTP 403s with issue on cloudfront. Do you know if there's an update setup route?

Comment: the last release was in August of this year, I am pretty sure that they've already included this code to the releases